# Oauth what redirect uri for wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, api, oauth-2.0, spotify, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating a free wordpress plugin that interacts with the Spotify API.
Users can download it, install it in their websites, activate it and they can then get specific information about a track.

Everything works in the v1 version. However i have trouble with the redirect uri.

I have to specify a specific redirect uri with Spotify, however the redirect differs on every instal, since its a different domain.

Should I redirect everything to a domain that i own, and redirect from there?
Is there a way to have a dynamic redirect uri?
Is there another method i dont know?

Please help!

Comment: On other plugins I´ve seen that need to provide an API with a redirect URI, what they do is they provide a Settings page in the backend where they indicate which is the URI that the user has to enter on the API side. 

What they do is use plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) to dynamically get the URL of your plugin directory in the current installation, and add to that and endpoint like $redirect_uri = plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'your-spotify-plugin-slug';

Comment: Check how they do it https://miled.github.io/wordpress-social-login/networks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this using a fixed redirect uri and the state parameter.
Every Oauth authorization is sent to the same redirect uri, which is a domain that I control.

I added the domain which the Oauth originated from to the state parameter.
From that point i am able to redirect the user back to the orignal domain. This whole proces goes so fast that it feels like a dynamic redirect URI, but in reality it is not.